# Enable dropdown based on another dropdown value in sharepoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, javascript, jquery, 2016

I have a dropdown: id="dropdown2" that is disabled upon loading the form.
I want it to be enabled when I select a specific value in another dropdown: id="dropdown1".

This is my current code but it is not working the way I want it. Upon loading the form, dropdown2 is disabled. But it is enabled regardless of whatever value I choose in dropdown1.

How can I fix it?

```
$('[id*="dropdown2"]').prop('disabled', true);

$('[id*="dropdown1"]').change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "Option1")
        {
           $('[id*="dropdown2"]').prop('disabled', true);
        } 
        else {
           $('[id*="dropdown2"]').prop('disabled', false);
        }
});
```

Comment: If you want to enable 2nd dropdown when `Option1` is selected, you have to change the condition in `if` block like: `$('[id*="dropdown2"]').prop('disabled', false);`. In short switch the conditions in if & else block. See my answer below for working code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is working code I have on list form:

```
//Disable on page load
$('select[title^="Review Status"]').prop('disabled', true);

//Enable or Disable based on Category field value
$('select[title^="Category"]').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "Other") {
        $('select[title^="Review Status"]').prop('disabled', false);
    } 
    else {
        $('select[title^="Review Status"]').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

Where, `Category` & `Review Status` are two choice columns. `Review Status` field will be enabled only when value of `Status` field will be `Other`.

**Output**:

Enabled when `Other` is selected:

[image]

Disabled when any other value is selected:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure why but I val() didn't work and I had to change it to this instead   
if ($('# option:selected').text() == "")